# Updating database in different thread in camel based application

Tags: database, apache-camel

I have a Camel based application which receives a request and gives the reply from cache but in between this process it updates the database which i want it to run in a different thread , can anyone tell me how can i achieve this, i tried with WireTap and SEDA but it does not work that way...any help appreciated.

`<camel:wireTap uri="seda:tap" processorRef="updateHitCountProcessor"/>`

In updateHitCountProcessor I have written code to update table
it is updating the database in same thread (i.e main route thread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
<camel:wireTap uri="ref:updateHitCountProcessor"/>
```

The processorRef attribute is creating and sending a new message, and not for tapping the existing message. So you should not use that.

The uri is used for sending the message which happens in a separate thread. So when you send it to the ref endpoint it will do that in another thread, and call your processor.

You can find details on the wire tap page at: http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the camel-seda component ([here](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html)):

> By default, the SEDA endpoint uses a single consumer thread, but you
> can configure it to use concurrent consumer threads.

You can add a thread pool to a SEDA endpoint like this:

`<from uri="seda:stageName?concurrentConsumers=5" />`

Comment: Its better to do from("seda:stageName?concurrentConsumers=")

Comment: OK, thanks I didn't know. The difference interests me, please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19511630/1292605